# How can i perform this query in NHibernate for getting child count

Tags: performance, nhibernate, criteria

```
select name, 
(select count(*) from products where products.category_Id=categories.Id) as productCount
from categories

session.CreateCriteria<Category>()
```

but whats next?

i don't even know how to search it in Google?

Answer (score 1):

think of your query like

```
SELECT     categories.Id, count(categories.Id)
FROM         categories inner join products on products.category_Id=categories.Id
group by categories.Id
```

I think they will produce the same result.

search google for

> nhibernate criteria join

and

> CreateAlias

Comment: i think that it should be better solution then inner join, any way it should be left join, cuz i dont wanna miss categories these haven't any product

Comment: you are right about both. the only reason i rewrote your query is because it will be easier to translate to nhibernate that way.